# Looping as many times as a given variable in Python

Tags: python, loops, numpy

Sorry for the wording in the title but I don't see any other way to express myself.

I'm dabbling a little bit in python right and the only way to create a loop that runs as many times as a number (something like `5.times do ... end` in Ruby) was to require `numpy` and then doing something like:

```
my_var = 5    

for num in numpy.arange(my_var):
    # stuff
```

which looks a little cumbersome to me. I would like to know whether there's a more *pythonic* way of doing this. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you run through [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html); had you done so, you would have seen [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function).

Comment: I admit I haven't. I've been learning python on-demand, like a lazy iterator =)

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida Pythonic way to learn Python is read a Python's book.

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida that would be reasonable approach, if you weren't demanding it from us

Comment: I agree. Thanks for helping, all the same.

Comment: I am truly amazed this kind of question gets up-voted. No wonder this site is now dominated by very poor material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the normal `range` method.

```
for num in range(5):
    # Do Something
```

`range` creates a list of size specified as the argument starting from 0 to the number-1, i.e. `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` in this case.

If you have larger number of iterations, creating a list takes up memory, use `xrange` instead in Python 2.x (`range` in Python 3.x) which creates an iterator which generates number on request instead of generating the whole list at once.

Answer (score 2):

Just use range:

```
for _ in range(my_var):
    #do stuff
```

Here, the `_` is a throwaway variable which means that you don't actually need it to run your loop, if you need each number in the range, then do

```
for i in range(my_var):
    #do stuff
```

In python-3.x, `range` returns an iterator whereas in python-2.x, it will return a list. To save memory in python, you can use `xrange` isntead which also return an iterator:

```
for i in xrange(my_var):
    #do stuff
```